# what the equivalent $from_email = _REG_EMAIL_; in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

anyone can help me for this problem $from_email = *REG_EMAIL*;
code from codeigniter 3

Comment: You are simply setting a variable to a Constant. That's just plain ole simple PHP and isn't a "CodeIgniter" thing. It would do you good to read the CodeIgniter userguides for 3 and 4?. Can you provide a code sample where this is being used in the code you are looking at?

Comment: $from_email = _REG_EMAIL_;
            $config = array(
              'mailtype'  => 'html',
              'charset'   => 'utf-8',
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => _REG_HOST_,
              'smtp_user' => $from_email,
              'smtp_pass' => _REG_PASS_,
              'smtp_crypto' => _REG_CRYPT_,
              'smtp_port' => _REG_PORT_,
              'crlf'    => "\r\n",
              'newline' => "\r\n",            Thanks for helping sir

Comment: Hi Rez, Lets get you on the right foot here. Can you have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to add in your code instead of putting it in a comment.